2024 Community Moderator Election Results
Moderator election #4 on Code Review has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the new moderator is:

They will be joining the existing crew shortly — please thank them for volunteering and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!
For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results here or view a summary report online.

Well deserved, congratulations!

It's like the elections in some countries: the winner is known in advance due to corruption. No suspense.  Except that, in our case, the winner deserves it and the election has been clean.
